# UITextField crashes when touched

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview

I'm having trouble debugging this. I have a UITextView that is crashing when touched. Only some of them are crashing like:  Account Type and VAT Quarter End.
This is what the screen looks like when crashed:

[image]

This is the code:

```
 @synthesize txtAccType = _txtAccountType;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  arrAccountType = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Freelancers", nil];

  //self.title = @"Account Setting";
  self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"AccountSetting", nil);

  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneBarButtonItem;

  arrCatId = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  arrCategory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  arrTotal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  tag = 0;
  [svAccountSetting setContentSize:CGSizeMake(280, 600)];
  arrCsvData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  quarterEndDatesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 @"April/Jul/Oct/Jan",
                 @"May/Aug/Nov/Feb",
                 @"June/Sep/Dec/Mar", nil];

  [self setAcc];
}

-(IBAction)selectAccountType
{
  [self.txtAccType resignFirstResponder];
  [svAccountSetting setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 6) animated:YES];
  [ActionSheetPicker displayActionPickerWithView:self.view data:arrAccountType selectedIndex:self.selectedIndex target:self action:@selector(itemWasSelected:) title: NSLocalizedString(@"Select_Account_Type", nil) ];
}

- (void)itemWasSelected:(NSNumber *)selectedIndexs {
  //Selection was made
  self.selectedIndex = [selectedIndexs intValue];
  self.txtAccType.text = [arrAccountType objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];
}
```

Since this project is older, I was wondering if some seasoned iOS developers might be able to help.

Comment: What message do you get in the debugger when it crashes?

Comment: The message of the crash ?

Comment: No message at all. That's another thing that's hard about this.

Comment: What iOS version are you testing on?

Comment: Try resignFirstResponder for all textView when touched.

Comment: @SanitLee Do you mean in the IBAction? `[UITextView resignFirstResponder];` Or do i put that in the ViewDidLoad?

Comment: What should I write exactly? I wrote `[UITextView resignFirstResponder];` in the IBAction and the app crashes.

Comment: From picture in your question, I see 5 textViews, so try resignFirstResponder for all of them just for experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting selectedIndex to 0 first:

```
[ActionSheetPicker displayActionPickerWithView:self.view data:arrAccountType selectedIndex:0 target:self action:@selector(itemWasSelected:) title: NSLocalizedString(@"Select_Account_Type", nil) ];
```

Answer (score -1):

**This Method crash on UITextView on Touch**

[ActionSheetPicker displayActionPickerWithView:self.view data:arrAccountType selectedIndex:self.selectedIndex target:self action:@selector(itemWasSelected:) title: NSLocalizedString(@"Select_Account_Type", nil) ];

Comment: Yes, I think so. But why?

Comment: Which version of ActionSheetPicker ?